# How the coordinates of the browser preview map to the coordinates in the PDF file

Tags: java, itext, coordinates, digital-signature, pdfbox

I now have a `PDF` file that is rendered in `PDFBox` into a single image per page

```
// load pdf and save image
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("some file")) {
  PDFRenderer render = new PDFRenderer(document);
  BufferedImage scaledImage = render.renderImageWithDPI(pageIndex, 326);
  // save image
}
```

The image saved in this step will be previewed in the browser. The user can drag and drop the image into this preview, and then I map this coordinate to the real PDF, but there is always some error. Here is how I mapped:

1. Get the preview in the browser's `width, height`, get drag and drop images in the preview in the upper `left corner of the x, y`
2. The backend fetches the PDF's `actual width, height`, and then computes the `width, height`, and height of the preview, resulting in a drag-and-drop image at the top left of the PDF in `x, y`
3. Because the origin of coordinates in PDF is the lower left corner of the document, the final formula for x and y is:

   - x: float targetX = (previewX 1.0F / previewWidth) pdfPageWidth;
   - y: float targetY = pdfPageHeight - (previewY 1.0F / previewHeight) pdfPageHeight - dragImageHeight
4. According to the previous calculation of x, y in this page PDF to draw this figure, but there are errors, and the error is obvious, **how can I do?**

#### Reference document

[iText](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/itext-questions-Digital-Signature-Position-td3050406.html)

**Edit**
I also try use iText:
```
    Rectangle cropBox = reader.getCropBox(firstPageIndex);

```
float widthRatio = renderRandomX * 1.0F / renderWidth;
float heightRatio = renderRandomY * 1.0F / renderHeight;

float offsetLLX = cropBox.getWidth() * widthRatio;
float offsetLLY = cropBox.getHeight() - cropBox.getHeight() * heightRatio;

Rectangle drawSignRect = new Rectangle(cropBox.getLeft() + cropBox.getWidth() * widthRatio,
    cropBox.getBottom() + offsetLLY,
    cropBox.getLeft() + offsetLLX + signImage.getWidth(),
    cropBox.getBottom() + offsetLLY + signImage.getHeight());
```

```

Comment: *"Because the origin of coordinates in PDF is the lower left corner of the document"* - this need not be, it merely is common. Simply read the [iText mailing list thread](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/itext-questions-Digital-Signature-Position-td3050406.html) you linked. That been said, other than that reference there is no relation to iText in your question, your code in particular is using PDFBox. Thus, you might want to drop the tag [tag:itext].

Comment: I also tried using `iText` to perform these operations and I ran into the same problem

Comment: *"but there are errors"* - you should describe them, probably by sharing examples.

Comment: Troubled almost a week, and finally solve the problem, the algorithm itself is no problem, but the third-party system will zoom the target image, calculate the position with this scaling is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubled almost a week, and finally solve the problem, the algorithm itself is no problem, but the third-party system will zoom the target image, calculate the position with this scaling is accurate.